# modify book.cls class to add one more section level (subsubsubsection)

Tags: sectioning, titlesec, books, sections-paragraphs

I would like to modify the `book.cls` class by adding one more section level (subsubsubsection). I know this can be done with the `titlesec` package, but I'm looking for a way to do this within a copy of the `book.cls` class I will then go on to call `mybook.cls`.

I have done the following, but the output I get is not quite right, I will attach a picture.

```
\newcommand\section{\@startsection {section}{1}{\z@}%
                                   {-3.5ex \@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                   {2.3ex \@plus.2ex}%
                                   {\normalfont\Large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsection{\@startsection{subsection}{2}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\large\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsection}{3}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsubsection}{4}{\z@}%
                                     {-3.25ex\@plus -1ex \@minus -.2ex}%
                                     {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                     {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}                                    
\newcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
                                    {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
                                    {-1em}%
                                    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                                      {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
```

```
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\newcounter {part}
\newcounter {chapter}
\newcounter {section}[chapter]
\newcounter {subsection}[section]
\newcounter {subsubsection}[subsection]
\newcounter {subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\newcounter {paragraph}[subsubsubsection]
\newcounter {subparagraph}[paragraph]
\renewcommand \thepart {\@Roman\c@part}
\renewcommand \thechapter {\@arabic\c@chapter}
\renewcommand \thesection  {\thechapter.\@arabic\c@section}
\renewcommand\thesubsection   {\thesection.\@arabic\c@subsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsection {\thesubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection  {\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsubsection}
\renewcommand\theparagraph    {\thesubsubsubsection.\@arabic\c@paragraph}
\renewcommand\thesubparagraph {\theparagraph.\@arabic\c@subparagraph}
```

```
\def\toclevel@chapter{0}
\def\toclevel@section{1}
\def\toclevel@subsection{2}
\def\toclevel@subsubsection{3}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@subparagraph{6}
\newcommand*\l@section{\@dottedtocline{1}{1.5em}{2.3em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsection{\@dottedtocline{2}{3.8em}{3.2em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsection{\@dottedtocline{3}{7.0em}{4.1em}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{10em}{5em}}
\newcommand*\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{12em}{6em}}
\newcommand*\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{7em}}
```

This is what happens if I set `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` and `\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}`:

[image]

Then this happens if I set the above to 3:

[image]

The extra text under Test Subsubsubsection is weird, I don't understand where it comes from.

The following is the code used to produce the output in the pictures:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,titlepage,openright]{mybook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\section{Test Section}
test
\subsection{Test Subsection}
test
\subsubsection{Test Subsubsection}
test
\subsubsubsection{Test Subsubsubsection}
test
\paragraph{Test Paragraph}
test
\subparagraph{Test Subparagraph}
test

\end{document}
```

Comment: don't just post fragments post a small complete example, if you just want this change it would be easier to load book and just redefine paragraph, rather than make a whole new class. easier still would be to add the new level at the bottom, \subsubparagraph then you would not have had to redfine anything

Comment: we can not use your example unless you add your class file, but I would be surprised if `titlesec` is compatible it will be expecting `\paragraph` after subsubsection I think. You can not need that package though as you are defining your headings in the class file, you should not need to change them.

Comment: You also need `\let\subsubsubsectionmark\@gobble`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I hope you would consider providing an answer based based on your comments.